# Repeating data for more efficiency

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Let's say I have a table `thread` and a table `response`, where I store threads and responses to threads that user submit in a forum.

I am currently counting the responses a given thread has like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM response
WHERE container_id = THREAD_ID
```

But, wouldn't it be better to just have another field (`number_of_responses` or something like that) in the thread table, add 1 to it every time it's responded? Then the query turn into something like this:

```
SELECT number_of_responses
FROM thread
WHERE id = THREAD_ID
LIMIT 1
```

Yes, I'd be repeating data, but isn't this approach more efficient? Or is it not recommended for some reason?

Comment: Is THREAD_ID unique in table? If not then your approach is not in 2NF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should use number_of_responses because it is generated data. You should only save in the database what the database can't calculate himself.
When you are experiencing slow tables you should add indexes or optimize the tables some other way.

Comment: what @IcedDante said: it is an option but it is dependent on how much rows you have to proceed. I recently did and `count(id) from table1 where a=1` on an table of more than 40 million rows and it was instant so it shouldn't be a problem.

Also: stored procedures make your database queries faster.

Comment: I think that's a good criteria, storing only what the database can't calculate for itself

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine part of it depends on how you are using the data. But I know a lot of forums I use list the number of replies alongside all the thread titles so if you are going to be displaying this information in thread listings and search results then it is a good option to consider.

If you only display it when the thread is opened then you might as well avoid the redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping a count column, while not 100% normalized, will result in faster page load times especially when your response tables starts to grow very large. If your response table contains text columns, which I suspect it does, counts get slow a lot sooner than if you have rows of small size (integers, varchars etc).

If you decide to go this route, I would suggest using a trigger on the response table to update the count on the appropriate thread row. This way you don't have to manage it within the code.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` is able to use indexes, so text columns do not affect count performance.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the count is a bad idea for all the reasons already given in the other answers. Instead of running separate queries to count the responses you can simply left join to the response table -

```
SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) 
FROM thread t
LEFT JOIN response r
    ON t.id = r.container_id
GROUP BY t.id
```

Using count on the LEFT JOIN will be very fast as it can use the index that should already exist for the foreign key.